# Group values and remove duplicates of groups based on a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pandas-groupby

I have a datafile which is the result of combining several sources that contain name information. Each name have a unique ID (Column ID).
Sorting the ID by column, I would like to remove the second/third source finding in the column Source.

**My output today:**

*(all the red rows are "duplicates" since we already got them from the first source (blue rows))*

[image]

**What I would like to achieve:**

[image]

How can I achieve this result? 
Is there a way to iterate row by row, where I remove duplicate of ID already when I iterate in the function "`for file in files:`" part of the code?
Or is it easier to do it in the "`df_merged`" before I output the dataframe to an  an excel file?.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import copyfile
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np



#Path
base_path = "G:/Till/"

# Def
def get_files(folder, filetype):
    list_files = []
    directory = os.fsencode(folder)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith("." + filetype.strip().lower()):
            list_files.append(filename)
    return list_files


# export files
df_result_e = pd.DataFrame()

files = get_files(base_path + "datasource/" + "export","xlsx")
df_append_e = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df_temp = pd.read_excel(base_path + "datasource/" + "export/" + file, "Results", dtype=str, index=False)
    df_temp["Source"] = file
    df_append_e = pd.concat([df_append_e, df_temp])


df_result_e = pd.concat([df_result_e, df_append_e])


print(df_result_e)


# match files
df_result_m = pd.DataFrame()

files = get_files(base_path + "datasource/" + "match","xlsx")
df_append_m = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df_temp = pd.read_excel(base_path + "datasource/" + "match/" + file, "Page 1", dtype=str, index=False)
    df_append_m = pd.concat([df_append_m, df_temp])

df_result_m = pd.concat([df_result_m, df_append_m])
df_result_m = df_result_m[['ID_Our','Name_Our','Ext ID']]
df_result_m.rename(columns={'ID_Our' : 'ID', 'Name_Our' : 'Name' , 'Ext ID' : 'Match ID'}, inplace=True)
df_result_m.dropna(subset=["Match ID"], inplace=True) # Drop all NA


data_frames = [df_result_e, df_result_m]

# Join files
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on=["Match ID"], how='outer'), data_frames)

#Output of files
df_merged.to_excel(base_path + "Total datasource Export/" +  datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M") + ".xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove them you can try `transform` with `factorize`

```
newdf=df[df.groupby('ID')['Source'].transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0])==0]
```

Comment: Thank you!, unfortunately i get error: `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Source'`. It's the "`.Source`" part that get the code stuck. Do I miss to `import .. as` anything? I have tried to limit the dataframe to only to columns (Source, ID) but still get the same error. Also update to latest version. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: @Wizhi try now ?, and print your name you may have white space in columns

Comment: That works beautifully. Huge thanks. I see now, that's why or rather me, never should name column similar to actual function/variable names. Thanks again!! Much appreciated.